# gcc4mbed compiler issue (c++)

Tags: c++, gcc, mbed

I have a project that **compiles just fine in the mbed online compiler**, but when I try to compile it localy using gcc4mbed it fails with:

```
MbedJSONValue.h:356:9: error: expected unqualified-id before '--' token
     int getc() {
         ^
MbedJSONValue.h:356:9: error: expected ')' before '--' token
MbedJSONValue.cpp:244:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
  }
  ^
In file included from MbedJSONValue.cpp:1:0:
MbedJSONValue.h:354:51: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
     input(const char * first, const char * last) {};
                                                   ^
make[2]: *** [NRF51822/MbedJSONValue.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [MbedJSONValue] Error 2
```

The code segment looks like this:

```
346: class input {
347: protected:
348:     const char * cur_;
349:     const char * end_;
350:     int last_ch_;
351:     bool ungot_;
352:     int line_;
353: public:
354:     input(const char * first, const char * last) : cur_(first), end_(last), last_ch_(-1), ungot_(false), line_(1) {};
355: 
356: int getc() {
357:     if (ungot_) {
358:         ungot_ = false;
359:         return last_ch_;
360:     }
361:     if (cur_ == end_) {
362:         last_ch_ = -1;
363:         return -1;
364:     }
365:     if (last_ch_ == '\n') {
366:         line_++;
367:     }
368:     last_ch_ = *cur_++ & 0xff;
369:     return last_ch_;
370: }
```

Comment: Should be unrelated to your problem, but the semi-colon after the constructor definition is not needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, Would you by any chance have an idea about how to make gcc4mbed compile with the same options as mbed online, or if there is an alternative to gcc4mbed?

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `#include <stdio.h>` with `#include <cstdio>` solved the issue.